# Samsung Browser versions 5.0.20-45 and 5.0.30-13 Android Select box issue

Tags: javascript, android, html, usability, galaxy

I have an issue where select boxes once opened and and option is picked I cannot then select another select. It appears to lock out any other selects from being clicked, they just wont open.

When opening the initial select and then blurring by clicking on another element like the body tag other select's can be picked. So in short the issue where I can not open a select only happens once an option has been picked from the initial select chosen.

Only happens in the newer Samsung internet browser on android versions above. Does anyone have any clue how to fix this issue?

You can check this here http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_forms_select_group.
1. select a weekday
2. select the hour
The hour list won't display.
Found the above link on the forum http://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/select-box-issue-on-samsung-internet-for-android-ver-5-and-above/201/302400?boardName=SDK&startId=00ks2~&startPage=8&curPage=10

Comment: Samsung internet browser? What real browser is "underneath" that?

Comment: Its a specific version of chromium that has been modified by samsung.

Comment: The best I have right now is '                        if( /Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
                            $(document).on("change", "select", function () {
                                $("select").add("*").off();
                            });
                        }'

Comment: A safer option: `                        if (/SamsungBrowser/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
                            $("select").change(function () {
                                setTimeout(function () {
                                    $(this).add("*").off("change");
                                }, 200);
                            });
                        }` this only looks at Samsung browser and also only looks at the `change` event binding so only effects dropdowns.